# phpmyadmin add text to an empty field?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin how can I add some text to an empty field but ignore all other fields which already have some text.

I can add text with the following command but it wipes out all the other text.

UPDATE products_description SET products_description = "new text"

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to try this query it will work fine...

UPDATE products_description SET products_description = "new text"
WHERE products_description = ""

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE products_description SET products_description = "new text" WHERE columnid = x
```

Replace `columnid` with the primary key column name, and `x` with the value of the entry you want to update

Answer (score 0):

In your insert query do not enter other fields but those fields will get default or null values

inert into yourtable(required_column) values('yourval')

or update query with using a primary key

Answer (score 0):

You can use where command -

```
Update products SET products_description="new text" where id=1;
```

something around that logic